# Git - Branch with the same name but different case doesn't show up

Tags: git

So I have a published branch of master, let's call it test. My co-worker creates a branch called TEST and publishes it. Now when I 'git fetch' it says that there's a new branch called TEST that's detected on the remote but when I do a 'git branch -r' it does not show up.
Here's the fetch results

```
   5ddcaca..70707f4  master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      TEST     -> origin/TEST
 + 890caf9...dc42ec8 test     -> origin/test  (forced update)
```

Now obviously creating a branch with the same name isn't a great practice but I can't find anything in reference to this problem. Is this just common knowledge? I feel like deleting my original 'test' branch will solve the problem but I don't want to accidentally delete his branch as well, or damage it in any way.

As I have to wait until tomorrow to talk with him, does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Edit: I'm using Windows 7 64bit, git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0, with the git bash

Comment: It'd be worth including the filesystem / OS you're using. Some file systems are case insensitive and will struggle with the TEST/test case.

Comment: I would locally and remotely rename your branch. It can get confusing if you have 20 branches all called test!!!!

Comment: What @Sam left untold is that the branches are stored as files (that contain the hash of the commit they point at) inside the `.git/refs/heads` directory. Because some file systems are either full case-insensitive or at least search case-insensitive, creating the files `test` and `TEST` in the same directory is either impossible (prohibited by the full case-insensitive file systems) or not practical (on the search case-insensitive ones; when `git` searches `TEST` it finds `test` and thinks they are the same).

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be sharing a remote repository with other people and will be frequently pushing short-lived test branches, I've found that good practice is to namespace your branches. For example, when creating your branches (or even just when pushing to the remote if you like), call your branch:

```
<your_name>/test
```

Then your colleague should use this convention:

```
<his_name>/test
```

This will avoid collisions altogether.